# Spring actuator/health results in HTTP 400 Bad request, JSON parse error

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i have an existing spring boot app. I just added actuator to the `pom.xml`
`org.springframework.boot`, `spring-boot-starter-actuator`.

actuator works
`actuator/health results` in error with `400` response code

from logs: it looks like spring failed to resolve some parameter.
below is the log.

> 019-05-15 14:38:24.747 DEBUG 8964 --- [nio-8090-exec-3]
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/actuator/health",
>   parameters={} 2019-05-15 14:38:24.748 DEBUG 8964 --- [nio-8090-exec-3]
>   s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped to Actuator web
>   endpoint 'health' 2019-05-15 14:38:24.754 DEBUG 8964 ---
>   [nio-8090-exec-3] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Could not
>   resolve parameter [1] in public java.lang.Object
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map): JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'eth': was
>   expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token
>   'eth': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')  at [Source:
>   (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 31] 2019-05-15 14:38:24.757 
>   WARN 8964 --- [nio-8090-exec-3]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
>   [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'eth': was expecting ('true',
>   'false' or 'null'); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token
>   'eth': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')  at [Source:
>   (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 31]]

Comment: Have you restarted after adding dependency to pom.xml file?

Comment: Updated formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have spring security running which needs a token along your request to result in a good status code. 
You can either add the token to your request or disable the security

```
security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false
```

Comment: tried the above and it gave the same result with HTTP GET on actuator/health. I think it is not able to find a handler for health endpoint

Comment: i am able to get /health working after removing unwanted key, params that accidentally went into my client's request. but now i see a new issue: overall status is DOWN as web3j is down.

Comment: "status": "DOWN",
    "details": {
        "myservice": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "app": "Alive and Kicking",
                "error": "Nothing! I'm good."
            }
        },
        "web3j": {
            "status": "DOWN",
            "details": {
                "error": "java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8545"
            }
        }
    }

Comment: my application connects to infura node to perform blockchain operations. not sure why it is trying localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8545"